# Ubuntu 16.04 - Can't align 4 monitors next to each other

Tags: drivers, 16.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display

I recently upgraded to a GeForce GTX 1070 to support a new monitor setup, but I'm having an issue when 4 monitors are connected.

Using the Display settings, I see all 4 monitors, but I can't align them correctly as there is a gap between two monitors no matter what placement. If I unplug one of the monitors it's not an issue.

I'm using the open source Nvidia 367 driver.

[image]

xrandr output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 9200 x 1920, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-4.8 connected primary 3440x1440+1920+0 (normal left inverted right    x axis y axis) 798mm x 335mm
   3440x1440     59.97*+  49.99  
   2560x1440     59.95  
   2560x1080     60.00  
   1920x1080     60.00    60.00    59.94    50.00    60.00    50.04  
   1720x1440     60.00  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93  
DP-2.1 connected 1920x1080+0+360 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00    60.05    60.00    50.04  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93  
DVI-D-0 connected 1200x1920+8000+0 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
   1920x1200     59.95*+
   1920x1080     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   640x480       59.94  
HDMI-0 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     60.00 +  59.94    23.97    60.05    60.00  
   1440x480      60.05  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.93  
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: Not sure if we can repair it, or if the bug is unfixable, but could you post the output of the command `xrandr` (from a terminal)?

Comment: @JacobVlijm Thanks. Added xrandr output as requested.

Comment: I forgot to ask: would you mind if the first screen is positioned 0,0 (should be on the top-left)?

Comment: @JacobVlijm 0, 0 would be ok.

Comment: @JacobVlijm For now I switched to XFCE, which doesn't have this issue.

Comment: Ah, sorry, planned it for today but forgot... Shouldn't be an issue on Ubuntu too, You might have bad luck. An xrandr command would most likely have fixed it. I will vote to close as non reproducable, since we cannot reproduce it anymore :)

Comment: Voted as non-repro, since op switched to another distro.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I would rather fixed it in Unity then switch to another Desktop Manager, so we can still continue working on it if that's possible.

Comment: Absolutely, but how would you test it?

Comment: I will vote to open if you can test it on Unity (*and* the issue occurs again).

Comment: @JacobVlijm I was able to fix it running some xrandr commands on the monitors. I haven't rebooted to test if keeps yet. Will do that shortly.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Rebooted and it's ok. Basically I used the --left-of command on the 4 monitor and then set the position relative to the 3rd monitor so they didn't overlap. Now when I go into displays I'm able to drap and drop the monitors as normal as well.

Comment: On Unity? If so, I'll vote to reopen and you can answer yourself.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Yes, on Unity.

Comment: Hi Andrew, could you write an answer once it gets reopened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this using xrandr commands. It was a bit of trial an error, so I don't have the exact commands that ultimately did the trick, but it involved using the xrandr --left-of command. With the above xrandr output I set the --left-of DVI-D-0 to output DP-4.8 and HDMI-0 --left-of to DVI-D-0. Once that was set I was able to set the positions relative to each other using both xrandr commands and the Displays settings.

For more info see the --left-of and --right-of commands under do useful things [here.](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Xorg_RandR_1.2)

Comment: I am curious if the xrandr output is different now than it was listed in your original question.  If it is different perhaps posting it in an update to your answer would help in understanding what was done.  Also, the current screen shot of Displays might help give a visual understanding.  Thanks :)