# How to align multiple monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

I have 3 monitors 1 connected via HDMI and 2 connected to a USB Dock and 1 of them is not accessible.

[image: Screen Alignment File]

If its important the monitor shown in yellow is the HDMI connected one.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.

When i try to drag the monitor selected on the right it remains locked to the "Built-in Display".

I found the following question + answer but not having much Linux experience i don't know how to use xrandr as discribed:
[Ubuntu 16.04 - Can't align 4 monitors next to each other](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866545/ubuntu-16-04-cant-align-4-monitors-next-to-each-other)

As other questions like this have the xrandr output i will also include it in case it helps:

`Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 7861 x 1200, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     59.94 +  59.93    40.00

   1680x1050     59.95    59.88

   1600x1024     60.17

   1400x1050     59.98

   1600x900      60.00

   1280x1024     60.02

   1440x900      59.89

   1280x960      60.00

   1368x768      60.00

   1360x768      59.80    59.96

   1152x864      60.00

   1280x720      60.00

   1024x768      60.00

   1024x576      60.00

   960x540       60.00

   800x600       60.32    56.25

   864x486       60.00

   640x480       59.94

   720x405       60.00

   640x360       60.00

DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 connected primary 1920x1080+1920+120 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94

   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94

   1600x1200     60.00

   1680x1050     59.88

   1280x1024     75.02    60.02

   1440x900      74.98    59.90

   1280x960      60.00

   1152x864      75.00

   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94

   1024x768      75.08    70.07    60.00

   832x624       74.55

   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25

   720x576       50.00

   720x576i      50.00

   720x480       60.00    59.94

   720x480i      60.00    59.94

   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94

   720x400       70.08

VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-2-2 connected 1920x1200+0+0 518mm x 324mm
   1920x1200     59.95*+
   1600x1200     60.00

   1280x1024     75.02    60.02

   1280x960      60.00

   1152x864      75.00

   1024x768      75.08    70.07    60.00

   832x624       74.55

   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25

   848x480       60.00

   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94

   720x400       70.08

DVI-I-1-1 connected 1920x1200+5941+0 518mm x 324mm
   1920x1200     59.95*+
   1600x1200     60.00

   1280x1024     75.02    60.02

   1280x960      60.00

   1152x864      75.00

   1024x768      75.08    70.07    60.00

   832x624       74.55

   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25

   848x480       60.00

   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94

   720x400       70.08

  1600x1200 (0xf7) 162.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1664 end 1856 total 2160 skew    0 clock  75.00KHz
        v: height 1200 start 1201 end 1204 total 1250           clock  60.00Hz
  1280x1024 (0xf8) 135.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1296 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  79.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  75.02Hz
  1280x1024 (0xd7) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  60.02Hz
  1280x960 (0xd9) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1376 end 1488 total 1800 skew    0 clock  60.00KHz
        v: height  960 start  961 end  964 total 1000           clock  60.00Hz
  1152x864 (0xfb) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1152 start 1216 end 1344 total 1600 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height  864 start  865 end  868 total  900           clock  75.00Hz
  1024x768 (0xff) 78.800MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1040 end 1136 total 1312 skew    0 clock  60.06KHz
        v: height  768 start  769 end  772 total  800           clock  75.08Hz
  1024x768 (0x100) 75.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1328 skew    0 clock  56.48KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  70.07Hz
  1024x768 (0xdf) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  832x624 (0x101) 57.284MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   832 start  864 end  928 total 1152 skew    0 clock  49.73KHz
        v: height  624 start  625 end  628 total  667           clock  74.55Hz
  800x600 (0x102) 50.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  856 end  976 total 1040 skew    0 clock  48.08KHz
        v: height  600 start  637 end  643 total  666           clock  72.19Hz
  800x600 (0x103) 49.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  816 end  896 total 1056 skew    0 clock  46.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  625           clock  75.00Hz
  800x600 (0xe2) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  800x600 (0xe3) 36.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock  35.16KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock  56.25Hz
  640x480 (0x10a) 31.500MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  720 total  840 skew    0 clock  37.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  481 end  484 total  500           clock  75.00Hz
  640x480 (0x10b) 31.500MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  664 end  704 total  832 skew    0 clock  37.86KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  491 total  520           clock  72.81Hz
  640x480 (0x10c) 30.240MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  704 end  768 total  864 skew    0 clock  35.00KHz
        v: height  480 start  483 end  486 total  525           clock  66.67Hz
  640x480 (0x10d) 25.200MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  60.00Hz
  640x480 (0xe5) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  720x400 (0x10e) 28.320MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   720 start  738 end  846 total  900 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  400 start  412 end  414 total  449           clock  70.08Hz
  1920x1200 (0x132) 154.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  74.04KHz
        v: height 1200 start 1203 end 1209 total 1235           clock  59.95Hz
  1600x1200 (0xf7) 162.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1664 end 1856 total 2160 skew    0 clock  75.00KHz
        v: height 1200 start 1201 end 1204 total 1250           clock  60.00Hz
  1280x1024 (0xf8) 135.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1296 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  79.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  75.02Hz
  1280x1024 (0xd7) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  60.02Hz
  1280x960 (0xd9) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1376 end 1488 total 1800 skew    0 clock  60.00KHz
        v: height  960 start  961 end  964 total 1000           clock  60.00Hz
  1152x864 (0xfb) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1152 start 1216 end 1344 total 1600 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height  864 start  865 end  868 total  900           clock  75.00Hz
  1024x768 (0xff) 78.800MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1040 end 1136 total 1312 skew    0 clock  60.06KHz
        v: height  768 start  769 end  772 total  800           clock  75.08Hz
  1024x768 (0x100) 75.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1328 skew    0 clock  56.48KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  70.07Hz
  1024x768 (0xdf) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  832x624 (0x101) 57.284MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   832 start  864 end  928 total 1152 skew    0 clock  49.73KHz
        v: height  624 start  625 end  628 total  667           clock  74.55Hz
  800x600 (0x102) 50.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  856 end  976 total 1040 skew    0 clock  48.08KHz
        v: height  600 start  637 end  643 total  666           clock  72.19Hz
  800x600 (0x103) 49.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  816 end  896 total 1056 skew    0 clock  46.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  625           clock  75.00Hz
  800x600 (0xe2) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  800x600 (0xe3) 36.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock  35.16KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock  56.25Hz
  848x480 (0x133) 33.750MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   848 start  864 end  976 total 1088 skew    0 clock  31.02KHz
        v: height  480 start  486 end  494 total  517           clock  60.00Hz
  640x480 (0x10a) 31.500MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  720 total  840 skew    0 clock  37.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  481 end  484 total  500           clock  75.00Hz
  640x480 (0x10b) 31.500MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  664 end  704 total  832 skew    0 clock  37.86KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  491 total  520           clock  72.81Hz
  640x480 (0x10c) 30.240MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  704 end  768 total  864 skew    0 clock  35.00KHz
        v: height  480 start  483 end  486 total  525           clock  66.67Hz
  640x480 (0x10d) 25.200MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  60.00Hz
  640x480 (0xe5) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  720x400 (0x10e) 28.320MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   720 start  738 end  846 total  900 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  400 start  412 end  414 total  449           clock  70.08Hz`

So do you know in simple terms how i can resolve my issue?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve my issue i used the following command, note this is specific to my config so edit as appropriate:

`xrandr --auto --output DVI-I-1-1 --mode 1920x1200 --right-of HDMI1`

Using the output from xrandr and the display settings window i discovered my monitors names see below from left to right as on the image in my question:

- DVI-I-2-2
- HDMI1
- DVI-I-1-1

I found my clue to the command in the following URL in the Dual Monitor section: http://blog.bodhizazen.com/linux/use-xrandr-to-set-a-screen-resolution/

I decided to try the command with the `--right-of` parameter in the hope it would change where the monitor was stuck to.

So whilst i can't explain the command completely i trusted that the `--auto` parameter wouldn't have a negative impact and the remaining parameters looked self explanatory to me:

- `--output` being the monitor you want to change
- `--mode` being the screen resolution you want
- `--right-of` being the monitor you want the output to be aligned with

Whilst this has answered my question if somebody can post a clear but generic answer i'll mark it as accepted :)